# Get Attribute of Object based on certain condition with variable

Tags: objective-c

I have some if else to get certain attributes from an object:

**Object**

```
NSString *firstValue;
NSString *secondValue;
NSString *thirdValue;
NSString *fourthValue;
```

I want to get the attribute based on certain if condition. For example what I need:

```
int condition;
NSString *attribute;

if(condition == 1)
    attribute = @"firstValue";
else if(condition == 2)
    attribute = @"secondValue";
else if(condition == 3)
    attribute = @"thirdValue";
else if(condition == 4)
    attribute = @"fourthValue";

NSString *value = object.attribute;
```

Can I do this in Objective C?

Comment: Take a look at KVC (key-value coding).

Comment: Thanks! I learn a lot from it!

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement would do the trick:

```
int condition;
NSString *attr;

//...

switch (condition) {
    case 1:
        attr = @"firstValue";
        break;
    case 2:
        attr = @"secondValue";
        break;
    case 3:
        attr = @"thirdValue";
        break;
}
```